# UISearchBar search button

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have found a tutorial on this website:

```
http://jduff.github.com/2010/03/01/building-a-searchview-with-uisearchbar-and-uitableview/
```

...but I am stuck here:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
// You'll probably want to do this on another thread
// SomeService is just a dummy class representing some 
// api that you are using to do the search
NSArray *results = [SomeSerivece doSearch:searchBar.text];

[searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
[searchBar resignFirstResponder];
self.tableView.allowsSelection = YES;
self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;

[tableData removeAllObjects];
[tableData addObjectsFromArray:results];
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

I can't understand what I have to write instead of SomeService. It is under comment, but I can't understand. I already have an array with all the content of the table view...so?? What do I have to do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like some service is the class that actually searches the array based on xyz criteria and returns the results. If I remember correctly UISearchBar automatically does this for you now - it is possible that the tutorial you are using is outdated.

I haven't used it personally, but the following may be more helpful; it uses a UISearchDisplayController, which handles the search results for you instead of forcing you to do it manually.

http://ygamretuta.me/2011/08/10/ios-implementing-a-basic-search-uisearchdisplaycontroller-and-interface-builder/

If you'd rather use the first tutorial, you'll have to create/find a search class to use on the array.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get the tutorial to work. Don't know why!!

Comment: Not sure how to help you unless you have some more information. What exactly is not working about it?